# Insertion sort in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm doing some exercises on Haskell. First I was asked to define a function `insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]` so that `insert x xs`
inserts x into the list xs in such a way that x is bigger than those
elements before it and smaller than or equal to the element that
follow it:

```
insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
insert x [] = [x]
insert x (y:ys) = if x < y 
                 then x:y:ys 
         else y : insert x ys
```

Now I need to use **insert** to define a function `insertionSort :: [Int] -> [Int]`. Here's my attempt:

```
insertionSort :: [Int] -> [Int]
insertionSort [x] = [x]
insertionSort (x:xs) = insert x insertionSort xs
```

> Error: Couldn't match expected type [Int] with actual type [Int] -> [Int]

Anyone know how I can fix this? Any insight is highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Don't use tags to increase visibility

Comment: What's supposed to happen when you sort the empty list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
insert x insertionSort xs
```

is calling `insert` with three arguments (`x`,`insertionSort`,`xs`).
Probably you want

```
insert x (insertionSort xs)
```

Answer (score 10):

While learning some sorting algorithms myself, I'd like to give you a few suggestions/improvements to your solution:

- Avoid non-exhaustive pattern matching at any case: `insertionSort [] = []`
- Take advantage of instances of `Ord` over a fixed type
- Consider *lambda lifting* by integrating insert into a where statement in order to get rid of the high-level function and save the argument `x`
- Consider *guards* over *if then else*

Which will result in:

```
insertionSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
insertionSort [] = []
insertionSort [x] = [x]
insertionSort (x:xs) = insert $ insertionSort xs
    where insert [] = [x]
          insert (y:ys)
              | x < y = x : y : ys
              | otherwise = y : insert ys
```

Comment: What's the advantage of lambda lifting? And can't you get rid of `insertionSort [x] = [x]`?

Comment: [Lambda lifting](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lambda_lifting) allows functions defined with `where` to be used as top-level functions. I'm not sure this applies to OP's code since their `insert` is already top-level. Yes, you can get rid of `insertionSort [x] = [x]`.

Comment: There's no obvious reason to move `insert` into a `where` clause here. It's a perfectly sensible thing in its own right, and passing one more argument isn't going to hurt anyone.

Comment: Another minor tweak here is to use an as-pattern by changing `(y:ys)` to `yy@(y:ys)`, and changing `x : y : ys` to `x : yy`. This is (perhaps) slightly more efficient since `yy` doesn't need to be recreated.